# Markdown in Python ins't rendering links correctly

Tags: python, flask, markdown, flask-flatpages

I am building a website using Python, Flask and Flask-FlatPages. From what I can gather, FlatPages uses the Jinja2 template engine and Markdown for simplifying the formatting of the content.

Until now I have been including images by writing the following raw HTML placed within the other markdown content:

```
<figure>
    <a href="/static/path/to/image.png" title="Full size">
        <img src="/static/path/to/image.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <figcaption>
        Figure caption.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I would like to simplify this process by using markdown's [link](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) syntax for images like so:

```
<figure>
    [![][image]][image]
    <figcaption>
        Figure caption.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
[image]: /static/link/to/image.png (Full size)
```

When I put this code into [Web Dingus](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus) it produces the following output:

```
<p><figure>
    <a href="/static/link/to/image.png" title="Full size">
        <img src="/static/link/to/image.png" alt="" title="Full size" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>
        Figure caption.
    </figcaption>
</figure></p>
```

However, when I put the same code into a markdown document for my website I get the following:

```
<figure>
    [![][image]][image]
    <figcaption>
        Figure caption.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

**Version info**

```
Flask==0.9
Flask-Assets==0.8
Flask-FlatPages==0.3
Flask-Markdown==0.3
Jinja2==2.6
Markdown==2.2.1
Werkzeug==0.8.3
```

Comment: How are you using FlatPages? Also, why don't you just write a macro?

Comment: @Blender I'm not sure what you mean by how am I using FlatPages. I thought that as markdown is meant to be able to handle images/links within tags that it could be a simple way around writing a lot of markup for each image.

Comment: It is, but if this is all that you're using it for, you aren't really "using" Markdown. FlatPages needs configuration. It doesn't just automatically translate templates.

Comment: @Blender Including images and links are not the only reason I am using markdown, I am also using it to include code blocks, headings, etc.

I have configured FlatPages as follows:

DEBUG = False
    DEBUG = False
    ASSETS_DEBUG = DEBUG
    FLATPAGES_AUTO_RELOAD = True
FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = '.md'
FLATPAGES_ROOT = 'pages'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
pages = FlatPages(app)

Comment: Standard Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags, but some extension can do this. See https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/80 for details.